# Unable to display table using an array of objects so that I am able to label rows using DT_RowId

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display a table using jQuery for control by passing in an array of objects rather than just an array.  I want to do this so that I am able to label the rows of the table using the DT_RowId label.  I need to do this so that I can add the delete functionality to the table available for the user.  Here are a few examples of what I am trying to do:

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/object_data.html

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/ids.html

I've tried formatting my data in both ways shown in these examples using the code below:

**searchWsConfigurations.jsp**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value='/styles/data_table.css'/>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value='/styles/data_table_proper.css'/>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value='/styles/demo_table_jui.css'/>" />
<script src="<c:url value='/javascript/jquery.dataTables.min.js' />" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

//Datatable transformations
$('#wsConfigurationTable').dataTable( {
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bDeferRender": true,
    "bProcessing" : true,
    "bServerSide" : true,
    "sAjaxSource" : "<c:url value='/maintenance/searchWsConfigurationsServerSideProcessingReport.htm'/>",
    "iDeferLoading" : 10,
    "bLengthChange": true,
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bSort": true,
    "aoColumns": [
                   { "mData": "testerId" },
                   { "mData": "date" },
                   { "mData": "hostName" },
                   { "mData": "ipAddress" },
                   { "mData": "alias" },
                   { "mData": "wsModel" },
                   { "mData": "operatingSystem" },
                   { "mData": "stRevisions" }],

    "bInfo": true,
    "bAutoWidth": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
});

}); 

</script>

<br>
<h2><tiles:getAsString name="heading" ignore="true"/></h2>
<br>

<a href="addWsConfiguration.htm"><img src="/vpdConsole/images/icons/add-icon-button_32x32.png" class="undecorated" style="float:right"/></a>

<table id="wsConfigurationTable" class="datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Tester ID</th>
        <th>Entry Date</th>
        <th>Hostname</th>
        <th>IP</th>
        <th>Alias</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>OS</th>
        <th>ST Rev</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I keep getting errors regarding the number of columns even though the server is returning what I expect.  Here is what I am getting in response:

```
{"sEcho":1,"iTotalRecords":13105,"iTotalDisplayRecords":13105,"aaData":[{"0":"Tester 1","1":"2013-05-14","2":"Host 1","3":"192.168.1.43","4":"Alias 1","5":"HP Proliant Server","6":"Red Hat Linux 5","7":"2.1.9","DT_RowId":"row_1","DT_RowClass":"visibleClass"},{"0":"Tester 1","1":"2013-05-14","2":"Host 1","3":"192.168.1.96","4":"Alias 1","5":"HP Proliant Server","6":"Red Hat Linux 5","7":"2.1.9","DT_RowId":"row_2","DT_RowClass":"visibleClass"},{"0":"Tester 1","1":"2013-05-15","2":"Host 1","3":"192.168.1.14","4":"Alias 1","5":"HP Proliant Server","6":"Red Hat Linux 5","7":"2.1.9","DT_RowId":"row_3","DT_RowClass":"visibleClass"},{"0":"Tester 10","1":"2013-05-14","2":"Host 10","3":"192.168.1.18","4":"Alias 10","5":"Sun Server X200","6":"Windows 7 Ultimate","7":"1.5.7","DT_RowId":"row_4","DT_RowClass":"visibleClass"},{"0":"Tester 10","1":"2013-05-14","2":"Host 10","3":"192.168.1.34","4":"Alias 10","5":"Sun Server X200","6":"Windows 7 Ultimate","7":"1.5.7","DT_RowId":"row_5","DT_RowClass":"visibleClass"},{"0":"Tester 10","1":"2013-05-15","2":"Host 10","3":"192.168.1.9","4":"Alias 10","5":"Sun Server X200","6":"Windows 7 Ultimate","7":"1.5.7","DT_RowId":"row_6","DT_RowClass":"visibleClass"},{"0":"Tester 100","1":"2013-05-14","2":"Host 100","3":"192.168.1.63","4":"Alias 100","5":"Sun Server X200","6":"Windows 7 Ultimate","7":"1.5.7","DT_RowId":"row_7","DT_RowClass":"visibleClass"},{"0":"Tester 100","1":"2013-05-14","2":"Host 100","3":"192.168.1.9","4":"Alias 100","5":"Sun Server X200","6":"Windows 7 Ultimate","7":"1.5.7","DT_RowId":"row_8","DT_RowClass":"visibleClass"},{"0":"Tester 100","1":"2013-05-15","2":"Host 100","3":"192.168.1.63","4":"Alias 100","5":"Sun Server X200","6":"Windows 7 Ultimate","7":"1.5.7","DT_RowId":"row_9","DT_RowClass":"visibleClass"},{"0":"Tester 1000","1":"2013-05-14","2":"Host 1000","3":"192.168.1.15","4":"Alias 1000","5":"Sun Server X200","6":"Windows 7 Ultimate","7":"1.5.7","DT_RowId":"row_10","DT_RowClass":"visibleClass"}]}
```

I'm not sure what I need to do to make this work.  I am able to display the table when using a regular array but when I switch it over to an array of objects, the error claims that the data is undefined sized and does not match the known number of columns.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try it without the aoColumns section, specifically the mData parameters. Those parameters are used to tell DataTables the name of the property in the object.  You are returning them in numerical form ("0" : "Tester 1").  If you want to use mData for some reason, you'll need to change your JSON - "testerId" : "Tester 1", "date" : "2013-05-14" etc.

Comment: OK I tried that and am still getting the same error.  Is there something else I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GqFcW/

Double click on any row and you'll get an alert with the row ID.  I modified your code to use an array of objects, and the objects use the mData names you provided instead of "0", "1", etc. Here's the first row as an example.

```
{"testerId":"Tester 1","date":"2013-05-14","hostName":"Host 1","ipAddress":"192.168.1.43","alias":"Alias 1","wsModel":"HP Proliant Server","operatingSystem":"Red Hat Linux 5","stRevisions":"2.1.9","DT_RowId":"row_1","DT_RowClass":"visibleClass"}
```

Alternatively, you could leave the array of objects the same as you had it, but modify mData to be

```
"aoColumns": [
                   { "mData": "0" },
                   { "mData": "1" },
```

and so on.

So uncomment out the `"bServerSide" : true` line, and add back your ajax call.  This should work.  If it doesn't, you may need to verify your JSON is returning as you believe it is.